# Python 2D convolution without forcing periodic boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution

I'm modeling a disease problem where each individual in a 2D landscape has a transmissibility described by a (radial basis) kernel function. My goal is to convolve the kernel with the population density such that the output captures the transmission risks across the landscape.

I performed the convolution using NumPy's 2D FFT and inverse-FFT functions. However, this forces a periodic/wrapped boundary condition in the result, which is unsuited for my model. Is there a way to convolve within the context of the original, fixed boundaries?

```
import numpy as np
import random
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

''' Landscape parameters ''' 
L = 10.
nx = 100
dx = L/nx
hs = .5 * dx  # half-step
ulist = np.linspace(hs, L-hs, nx)

''' Radial Basis Function Kernel '''
alpha = 1.
i, j = ulist.reshape(nx,1), ulist.reshape(1,nx)
r = np.minimum(i-ulist[0], L-i+ulist[0])**2 + np.minimum(j-ulist[0], L-j+ulist[0])**2
rbf = sqrt(1 / (2 * alpha ** 2))
ker = np.exp(-(rbf * r) ** 2)
ker = ker/np.sum(ker)

''' Population Density '''
ido = np.random.randint(nx, size=(1000,2)).astype(np.int)
og = np.zeros((nx,nx))
np.add.at(og, (ido[:,0], ido[:,1]), 1)

''' Convolution via FFT and inverse-FFT '''
v1 = np.fft.fft2(ker)
v2 = np.fft.fft2(og)
v0 = np.fft.ifft2(v1*v2)
dd = np.abs(v0)

plt.plot(ido[:,1], ido[:,0], 'ko', alpha=.5)
plt.imshow(dd, origin='origin')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you need to pad `og` with zeros, and expand `ker` accordingly (since it is already cyclically shifted, you just need to expand it more to fit the size of `og`).

Padded `og` (300x300):
[image: padded <code>og</code>]
Original `ker` (100x100):
[image: original <code>ker</code>]
Expanded `ker` (300x300):
[image: expanded <code>ker</code>]

Code:

```
pad = 100
og = np.pad(og, pad, mode='constant')
new_ker = np.zeros_like(og)
new_ker[:nx//2,:nx//2] = ker[:nx//2,:nx//2]
new_ker[:nx//2,-nx//2:] = ker[:nx//2,-nx//2:]
new_ker[-nx//2:,:nx//2] = ker[-nx//2:,:nx//2]
new_ker[-nx//2:,-nx//2:] = ker[-nx//2:,-nx//2:]
ker = new_ker

# doesn't change
v1 = np.fft.fft2(ker)
v2 = np.fft.fft2(og)
v0 = np.fft.ifft2(v1*v2)

# unpadding the result
v0 = v0[pad:-pad,pad:-pad]
```

(Sorry for the messy expanding, you can do it directly when generating the kernel. I just wanted to separate the expansion part.)

Original result:
[image]
Result with padding:
[image: padded result]

If you do not mind using `scipy`, it can do all this for you (including other variants of boundary conditions). See [`fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve) or [`convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html#scipy.signal.convolve2d) for more options. Note that you *do not* have to pre-roll your kernel to use these functions (that is, the maximum should be in the center, not in the corners). Example code (produces the same result as the manual padding above):

```
# unroll the kernel (again, can be done directly when generating `ker`)
ker = np.roll(ker, 50, 0)
ker = np.roll(ker, 50, 1)

from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
dd = fftconvolve(og, ker, mode='same')
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use `fft` based methods, you are always introducing periodic-ness in the problem, essentially, by definition.

If you don't want this you should first of all define what it is that you want at the mathematical modelling level before the computational level.

Keep in mind a few tricks that in my experience are very helpful in many cases:

-- Embed your problem in a larger 2d space to reduce periodicity effects. In other words, push the periodic boundaries as far as possible to simulate a 'free-space' situation.

-- Use discrete cosine transform instead. Cosine transform has the effect to simmetryze the boundary condition. It works as if beyond each boundary there was a mirror reflection of your data. In some kind of problems this is used to simulate a reflective boundary condition.